# Adding drop-down list checking in product selector with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, html-select

I'm working on a project for school where I need to make a product selector using jquery!
It worked fined with my code ( http://jsfiddle.net/rda9Q/6/ ) and the checkbox were working, it was all automatic and good, until I tried to use drop-down lists!
Surely because I have no idea how to make my code react after the value is changed or something...

The code that I need to reproduce so that it react on value changing in the list:

```
$('.filtercondition:checked').each(function(){
    className += $(this).attr('value');
});
```

I just need to keep the automatism and the order and value. All I need is the part that will also react on value changing in drop-down lists because I will add some elements after!

Thank you beforehand for future help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.filtercondition').change(function () {
    var className = '';
    $('.filtercondition[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
        className += this.value;
    });
    className += $('select.filtercondition').val();

    if (className.length == 0) className = 'mainresult';

    $('.results').hide();
    $('#' + className).show();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L3SdD/)